# Rails Select Form: How do I populate the method parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, erb

Thanks for reading, I am not sure how to write the method parameter for the Rails Form Helper for Select Boxes.

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class School
  attr_accessor :students
  def initialize
    students = []
  end
end

class Student
    attr_accessor :teacher
    atrr_accessor :student_name
end

class Teacher
    attr_accessor :teacher_name
end

@teacher_list = ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Brown','White']
```

And I want to have a select box that will show which teacher each student has and allows me to select different teachers. I want to be able to parse the params generated and sent to the controller in case I need to update it, but I also want the correct value to show up selected.

I don't know how to write the method parameter such that it selects the correct value to show as selected, I am doing something like this:

```
<%= form_for :school, url: update_path do |f| %>
  <% school.students.each do |student| %>
  <% f.select("[students]#{student.student_name}[teacher][teacher_name]" options_for_select(@teacher_list),{prompt => 'Select Teacher for student'}) %>
<% end %>
```

This is obviously wrong, but I want to be able to generate the params hash in an way that I can easily parse it.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: These are the pages I've used to try to figure this out:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a while ago. I created a table for this, the table is roles and the model is role.

The User Model has many and belogs to many roles. This means that Many user can have different roles and each role can have different users, but a one to many relationship (`has_many :roles`) is enough

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

Role Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I create an additional table roles_users to manage the join relationship between user and role.

```
create_table(:roles_users) do |t|
    t.belongs_to :role, index: true
    t.belongs_to :user, index: true
end
```

This is the form, the value of the select form is calculated with Role.all.collect.

```
<%= form_for @user |f| %>
<%= f.select(:roles_id, Role.all.collect {|p| [ p.role, p.id ]}, {:selected => @user.roles_id}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```

This is how I have done it, in the next days I may have the time to review this answer and improve it. I hope it helps you. 
Sorry if it is not very good

Thanks

Fabrizio